# I need to customize name in header section of formbuilder when we drag and drop any component in formio angular

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, formbuilder, formio

[You can see image where i want to customize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXuC5.png)

- i want to remove component word written after **Text Field**
- I have try many things but not getting proper solution for it not able to find solution from documentation.
- I have tried using css also to fix my issue bu not ablw to achieve it using css also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to remove word component from header section of popup open when add and edit any component from any section
example
if we drag and drop text field it opens popup where in header it come like "*TEXT FIELD COMPONENT*".

i only need "*TEXT FIELD*" to be displayed on UI